# Issue sonarqube gradle task no working with java 11

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube

I have a project with Gradle and Sonarqube plugin, after upgrade java from 8 to 11 the Sonarqube plugin stop working.

I read all this post searching for a solution without luck.

https://community.sonarsource.com/t/java-analysis-using-java-10-and-overall-java-support/2245

https://github.com/sonargraph/sonar-sonargraph-integration/issues/14

https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-gradle/

For reproducing the issue clone the official Sonarqube scanner for Gradle: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-gradle, add

```
sourceCompatibility = '11'
```

to the build.gradle and configure the project with java 11. Execute

```
./gradlew sonarqube
```

the error is

```
> Task :sonarqube FAILED

Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.
> javax/xml/bind/ValidationEventHandler
```

Any help will be appreciated.